# Updating multiple nodes in AVL tree efficently?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, avl-tree

I have an AVL tree with n nodes, where they are sorted by index 1,2,3,4...,n

I want to increase the index of all nodes in [i,j] by d, how can I do this in O(log n)?

**For example:**

I my tree had 1,2,3,4 and d=3 and I got [2,4] then the new AVL tree will hold 1,5,6,7

Comment: Interesting puzzle. If every node's index larger than i is incremented the tree structure does not need to change (i.e. remains a valid BST and is AVL balanced) -- this is your example case. A more interesting example would be where j is smaller than the largest index.

Comment: If the indexes are sequential numbers from 1 to n, then some choices of `d` and `[i,j]` will result in duplicated indexes. For example, if the tree has 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 and d=3, and you get [2,4], then the new tree will hold 1,5,5,6,6,7,7. That just makes a mess out of the tree, and clearly can't be solved in O(logn) time even if you do allow the tree to have duplicates. So I think the description of the problem is incomplete.

Comment: @user3386109 you can suppose duplicated won't be made (by choosing right range and d etc...)

Comment: @wcochran my example excepts the first element

Comment: Please construct an example with letters as keys and an interval that includes neither the node first nor the one last *before the change*. Is it possible that this range ends up first/last *after the change*.

Comment: (To see the mess possible, picture a perfect binary tree for characters a c e g i k m and shift the value of nodes with in-order zero based ordinal 1to3 up by 5 character values (the resulting key order should be a h i j k l m). Plus you'll have to specify (*in the question* - this is not chat) what to do with duplicate keys, as [user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66250148/updating-multiple-nodes-in-avl-tree-efficently#comment117128878_66250148) may have commented. (I have more than one idea what *index of a tree node* may be: Please add to the question the definition to use.)